# I Can't read from the server-side socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

First of all, the android application will connect to the server (PC).
Then the android will send a message.
And finally the android application should receive a message from the server.

When I send the message from the android to the Server, everything goes well.
However, when it comes to reading from socket inside the android app, I can't receive anything.

Here is the Server code

```
    ServerSocket Sock = new ServerSocket(7777);
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection...\n");
    Socket connectionSocket = Sock.accept();
    System.out.println("Client In...");
    BufferedReader inFromClint = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    String txt = inFromClint.readLine();
    System.out.println(txt);
    String MsgToClient = "{\"LoginFlag\":\"N\"}";  //{"LoginFlag":"P"}
    printwriter.write(MsgToClient);
    printwriter.flush();
    printwriter.close();
    System.out.println("\nMsg Sent");
    Sock.close();
```

And this is sample of the Android app:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try
          {
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
             PrintWriter printwriter = null;
             port = 7777;
              client = new Socket("192.168.1.2", port);
              printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
              printwriter.write(SMsgLog);
              printwriter.flush();
              printwriter.close();
              bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
              if( bufferedReader.ready() )
              {
                  RJasonLog = bufferedReader.readLine();   //rcv as jason
              }
              else
              {
                 RJasonLog = null;
              }
              if (RJasonLog != null)
              {
                 JSONObject objectRcv = new JSONObject(RJasonLog);
                  if (objectRcv != null)
                  {
                     RMsgLog = objectRcv.getString("LoginFlag");  //Jason Key from the server
                   }
               }
               RMsgLog = "N";
               if(RMsgLog.equals("N"))
               {                                     
                  alert.showAlertDialog(Login.this, "Login failed..", "Username/Password is incorrect", false);
               }
                else
                      alert.showAlertDialog(Login.this, "Login failed..", "Please Try Again", false);


               client.close();
           }

           catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
 }).start();
```

Comment: You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator, or use `println()`. NB `flush()` and `Sock.close()` are both redundant here, as are `RMsgLog = "N"; if(RMsgLog.equals("N"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clienr is trying to read a line. But the server is not sending a line with `printwriter.write(MsgToClient);`. Change to `printwriter.write(MsgToClient + "\n");` to send a line.

Comment: Or `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

---

I solved it with the help from the comments.

I removed `printwriter.close();` on client side.

And then I added `\n` In both client and server before sending the message

---

Answer (score -1):

Don't close the output stream in client code, Remove this line:

```
printwriter.close();
```

Stream should not be closed until connection is alive. It should be closed at the end when you are done with the socket. Closing connection will also close the streams associated with it.

Here is small description about the getOutputStream method.

> getOutputStream
>
> public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException Returns an
>   output stream for this socket. If this socket has an associated
>   channel then the resulting output stream delegates all of its
>   operations to the channel. If the channel is in non-blocking mode then
>   the output > stream's write operations will throw an
>   IllegalBlockingModeException.
>
> **Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.**
>
> Returns: an output stream for writing bytes to this socket. Throws:
>   IOException - if an I/O error occurs when creating the output stream
>   or if the socket is not connected.

Comment: Do you mean 'shouldn't be closed *while* connection is alive'?